# Prove or disprove: if $2a^{2}=b^{2}$, then a and b are divisible by 2

Tags: linear-algebra

The solution to $2a^{2}=b^{2}$

is b= $\mp \sqrt{2}a$

Doesn't this mean that *b* will never be an integer? Unless *a* is $ \sqrt2$, in which case *a* isn't an integer.

Comment: the only solution in which $a$ or $b$ is rational (let alone integer-valued or even) is $a=b=0$.  See Tim.Ratigan's answer.

Comment: As Stefan pointed out, there is the trivial solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $2a^2=b^2$ it means $b$ must be even (because only an even number squared leads to an even number). So let $b=2m$ - this leads to:$$2a^2=(2m)^2=4m^2$$$$\therefore a^2=2m^2$$and hence $a$ must be even (for same reasons as above).

Thus both $a$ and $b$ must be even.

Comment: **REMARK** (This implies that $a$ and $b$ have at least one common factor (namely, $2$)).

Comment: Correct - this is usually a step in proving that $\sqrt{2}$ is not a rational number.

Comment: @Mufasa : If you assume $a$ and $b$ are integers, then indeed $a$ and $b$ must be even, however, more specifically, they must be zero (see Tim.Ratigan's answer).  Literally speaking, you did answer the OP's question correctly.

Comment: @StefanSmith - I understand and was assuming the OP was following a proof by contradiction of $\sqrt{2}$ not being a rational number. In that case, the first step is to assume that it is indeed rational and can be written as $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a$ and $b$ are two integers with no common factors. This leads to the step posted by the OP which in turn leads to $a$ and $b$ both being even and hence having a common factor. Therefore first assumption must have been incorrect.

Comment: @Mufasa : OK, I understand why you seem to have withheld information from the OP.  It does seem likely that the OP is trying to prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Answer (score 1):

As Stefan Smith kindly pointed out, $a=b=0$ is a trivial solution in the integers.  But what if $a,b\in \Bbb N$?

Assume $2a^2=b^2$.  Then $2|b^2$, which implies (by unique prime factorization) that $2|b$.  Therefore we can write $b^2=4k^2$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$.  Then $2a^2=4k^2\Longrightarrow 2k^2=a^2$.  This inductive step begins a process of [infinite descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent) which ultimately proves that $a$ and $b$ cannot be natural numbers, and therefore $\sqrt 2=\frac{b}{a}$ cannot have rational solutions (this takes note of the fact that the canonical form for $\sqrt 2$ should be greater than $0$).

Comment: Good answer, and sorry to nitpick, but the original equation is $2a^2 = b^2$, which has solution $a=b=0$, and of course $0$ is divisible by $2$.

Comment: I assumed use of $\Bbb N=\{n\mid n\in\Bbb Z,\,n>0\}$.  I just realized the question was talking about the integers, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: the OP asks whether $a$ and $b$ can be integers, and does not restrict their sign (positive, negative, or zero).